# driver for Cloud Cap Christa IMU

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've searched in vain for a driver for the Cloudcap Crista IMU, so it looks like I will have to write/modify a driver to convert to ROS message format.  I have a specific example driver in C++ that came with the unit along with several other source files as dependencies.

I have not been able to find specifics regarding the creation of the ROS wrapper that implements this driver.  I can post the example code if need be.

Thanks in advance
Bruce

06/15/15
Thank you Kleinma.  I did find your driver about a month ago and am in the process of putting it all together with robot_localization.  At first I had little luck, but after a late night AHA!, I discovered that it was timing-out due to the latency of my setup.  It is working fine now after making that adjustment.  Thank you so much, I thought I was the only one in the universe using this accelerometer.  Also great work on the agricultural applications!

Thanks also goes to the ROS community at large.  Such a gold mine of knowledge!  I did not think I could mix cpp and python in ROS, but the answer was here within the community.  I still have a long way to go, but now I have access to your wealth of resources and experience.   Many thanks to all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204378/driver-for-cloud-cap-christa-imu/) by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-06**:
If you do start writing a wrapper/driver, please pay attention to standards / best practices for IMUs in ROS. See [ros-infrastructure/rep#95](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/95) for some recent discussion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find a ROS driver [here](https://github.com/cwrucutter/christa_imu_driver). "Crista" is mispelled (as "Christa"). However, it should work just fine.

---

Originally posted by [kleinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22806/kleinma/) with karma: 48 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2